# Word for Helpful articles & videos?

Tags: word-request, synonyms

I'm writing a mail to my juniors and sharing a document with them in it. The document includes some links to videos and articles to help them understand a particular topic. I'm referring to these articles and videos by 'videos and articles' every time. I know it's not wrong but still, it looks very odd to mention these words again and again. Can anyone suggest a synonym or an alternative to it?

Comment: reference materials?

Comment: **Aids** would also work.

Comment: You said - *"it looks very odd to mention these words again and again"* - which means that you are mentioning those things several times. Given that, no matter what alternative/synonym you use, you will be mentioning them several times. The problem is not the terminology, but the repeated mention of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most generally they could be called **sources** or **information sources**. This is a mostly context-neutral way to phrase it and does not imply how the articles and videos should be used.

Another word you could use is **references**, which implies an information source about a specific topic or category of knowledge. It also implies that the information is provided on an as-needed basis, rather than a mandatory one.

Finally, in the most formal and academic of contexts, these could be called **supplemental materials**. The word [supplement](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supplement) refers to something that completes or supports something else, or makes up for a deficiency elsewhere. The implication is that these materials support and reinforce knowledge, but aren't required to be read or viewed.